What is a C∞ mapping?
I am reading continuum mechanics, where I encountered the definition of a coordinate system.
It states that a coordinate system {$x^a$}, (a=1,2,3) on $R^3$ is a $C^∞$ mapping ($x^1$, $x^2$, $x^3$) of an open set $U_a$⊂$R^3$ to $R^3$ such that
(1) the range is an open set $U_x$ ⊂ $R^3$, and 
(2) the mapping
($z^1$, $z^2$, $z^3$) ↦ ($x^1$($z^1$, $z^2$, $z^3$), $x^2$($z^1$, $z^2$, $z^3$), $x^3$($z^1$, $z^2$, $z^3$))
of $U_z$ to $U_x$ has a $C^∞$ inverse, whose components are denoted $z^i$($x^1$,$x^2$,$x^3$).
I have two questions:

I know that $C^∞$ means a function that can be differentiated infinite times. But what does this $C^∞$ mapping mean?
Why is the mapping defined on an open set, and the boundaries not included in the definition?


Why did you write ## Heading ##?

The words "mapping" and "function" are synonyms. A $C^\infty$ mapping is the same thing as a $C^\infty$ function, which means what you said, namely a function that can be differentiated infinitely many times (in more careful detail, it means all mixed partial derivaties of all orders of that function exist).
The definition of "differentiable at the point $z = (z^1,z^2,z^3)$" ordinarily requires (among other things) that there exist a positive radius $r$ such that all points whose distance from $z$ is $<r$ are in the domain of the function. For this to be true at all points $z$ in the domain is precisely what it means for the domain to be open. In other words, the ordinary expectation when one is talking about a differential function is that the domain of that function be open.
That open-ness requirement can be weakened if needed, like this: Whether or not the domain of the function is open, one can define the function to be $C^\infty$ if there exists an open set containing the domain, and there exists an extension of the function to that open set, such that the extended function is $C^\infty$.
You can probably find all of these things and more laid out carefully in a textbook on mathematical analysis or differential topology, although not necessarily a textbook on general-topology as you have tagged your post.
